# Call exe requiring a text input file from a different folder

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a small `.exe` file that requires an input file (`in.txt`) and which produces an output file (`out.txt`). I have a python script that I want to call this in place of using a batch file, and I found that none of the following work:

```
import subprocess

dir_cwd  = Path(r"current/folder")
dir_program = Path(r"path/to/folder/containing/exe")
dir_dest = Path(r"path/where/i/actually/want/to/store/stuff")

# this:
for i in xrange(n):
  p = subprocess.Popen([dir_program/"program.exe"])
  p.wait()

# or:
subprocess.call([dir_program/'someprog.exe'])
```

It doesn't seem to work unless I actuall move into the folder and do:

```
import os
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

dir_cwd  = Path(r"current/folder")
dir_program = Path(r"path/to/folder/containing/exe")
dir_dest = Path(r"path/where/i/actually/want/to/store/stuff")

os.chdir(dir_dest)
for x in runs_list:
    os.system("program.exe")
    shutil.move("out.txt", dir_dest/"out.txt")
os.chdir(dir_cwd)
```

I don't want to have to be changing directories during this script. The exe is an old program compiled from an old `fortran` code and I'm wondering if that might be the issue. Does anyone know why I can't run the exe file using some path to the folder, but have to be in the folder itself instead?

Comment: if `program.exe` expects file in folder in which it runs and it can't run as `program.exe path/to/in.txt` then you have to change folder.

Comment: when you in folder `"A"` and you run `dir_program/"program.exe"` then `program.exe` treats `"A"` as `CWD` - `Current Working Directory` and you can change it only using `cd` / `chdir`. You will have the same problem with script in Python or any other language - so it is not problem with old `fortran`. Simply system (Windows/Linux) works this way.

Comment: So given that I can't recompile the source code to alter the input path, this means I am required to to the chdir and no other options exist?

Comment: yes, you have to change folder. Or move `in.txt` to folder in which you run script. On Linux you could eventually create soft link `ln -s` to have exactly the same file in two folders.

Comment: Popen has a `cwd` (current working directory) argument, why can't you just set that to your in.txt file's location? Then the fortran program should be able to read it.